# R's `chol` differs from MATLAB's `cholcov`. How to do a Cholesky-alike covariance decomposition?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, covariance, matrix-factorization

I've been trying to reproduce a cholesky-like covariance decomposition in R - like it is done in Matlab using `cholcov()`. Example taken from https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/cholcov.html.

Result of the original `cholcov()` function as of their example:

```
T =
   -0.2113    0.7887   -0.5774         0
    0.7887   -0.2113   -0.5774         0
    1.1547    1.1547    1.1547    1.7321
```

I am trying to replicate this `T` in R. I tried:

```
C1 <- cbind(c(2,1,1,2), c(1,2,1,2), c(1,1,2,2), c(2,2,2,3))
T1 <- chol(C1)
C2 <- t(T1) %*% T1
```

My result:

```
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]         [,4]
[1,] 1.414214 0.7071068 0.7071068 1.414214e+00
[2,] 0.000000 1.2247449 0.4082483 8.164966e-01
[3,] 0.000000 0.0000000 1.1547005 5.773503e-01
[4,] 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.290478e-08
```

`C2` recovers `C1`, but `T1` is quite different from MATLAB's solution. I then thought maybe it would be a Cholesky composition of the covariance matrix:

```
T1 <- chol(cov(C1))
```

but I get

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]         [,4]
[1,] 0.5773503 0.0000000 0.0000000 2.886751e-01
[2,] 0.0000000 0.5773503 0.0000000 2.886751e-01
[3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5773503 2.886751e-01
[4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 3.725290e-09
```

which is not right either.

Could anyone give me a hint how `cholcov()` in Matlab is calculated so that I could replicate it in R?

Comment: What is your definition of "right"? Such results are not likely to be unique and that help page says that rows that are all zero will be omitted. as are rows 4 of both of those results.

Comment: Haha - thanks :) I know how to - great answer! Really appreciate your quick reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially abusing R function `chol` in this case. The `cholcov` function from MATLAB is a composite function.

- If the covariance is positive, it does Cholesky factorization, returning a full-rank upper triangular Cholesky factor;
- If the covariance is positive-semidefinite, it does Eigen decomposition, returning a rectangular matrix.

On the other hand, `chol` from R only does Choleksy factorization. The example you give, `C1`, falls into the second case. So, we should resort to `eigen` function in R.

```
E <- eigen(C1, symmetric = TRUE)
#$values
#[1] 7.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 2.975357e-17
#
#$vectors
#           [,1]          [,2]          [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] -0.4364358  0.000000e+00  8.164966e-01 -0.3779645
#[2,] -0.4364358 -7.071068e-01 -4.082483e-01 -0.3779645
#[3,] -0.4364358  7.071068e-01 -4.082483e-01 -0.3779645
#[4,] -0.6546537  8.967707e-16 -2.410452e-16  0.7559289

V <- E$vectors
D <- sqrt(E$values)  ## root eigen values
```

Since numerical rank is 3, we drop the last eigen value and eigen vector:

```
V1 <- V[, 1:3]
D1 <- D[1:3]
```

[image]

Thus the factor you want is:

```
R <- D1 * t(V1)  ## diag(D1) %*% t(V1)
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]          [,4]
#[1,] -1.1547005 -1.1547005 -1.1547005 -1.732051e+00
#[2,]  0.0000000 -0.7071068  0.7071068  8.967707e-16
#[3,]  0.8164966 -0.4082483 -0.4082483 -2.410452e-16
```

We can verify that:

```
crossprod(R)  ## t(R) %*% R

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    1    1    2
#[2,]    1    2    1    2
#[3,]    1    1    2    2
#[4,]    2    2    2    3
```

---

The `R` factor above is not as same as the one returned by `cholcov` due to different algorithms used for Eigen factorization. R uses LAPACK routine [`DSYVER`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d8a/group__double_s_yeigen_ga2ad9f4a91cddbf67fe41b621bd158f5c.html#ga2ad9f4a91cddbf67fe41b621bd158f5c) in which some pivoting is done so that eigen values are non-increasing. MATLAB's `cholcov` is not open-source, so I'm not sure what algorithm it uses. But it is easy to demonstrate that it does not arrange eigen values in non-increasing order.

Consider the factor `T` returned by `cholcov`:

```
T <- structure(c(-0.2113, 0.7887, 1.1547, 0.7887, -0.2113, 1.1547, 
-0.5774, -0.5774, 1.1547, 0, 0, 1.7321), .Dim = 3:4)
```

We can get eigen values by

```
rowSums(T ^ 2)
# [1] 1.000086 1.000086 7.000167
```

There are some round-off error because `T` is not precise, but we can see clearly that eigen values are `1, 1, 7`. On the other hand, we have `7, 1, 1` from R (recall `D1`).

Comment: Thanks! This is precisely what I needed - I'll just write my own composite function then for my script.